# how to pass parameters to an http request that call which takes the POST payload as form-data programmatically

Tags: javascript, json, rest, https

I have an HTTP POST request that accepts the body as form-data.

```
grant_type: client_credentials
```

when I use this API in an application, I need to pass a client_id and client_secret parameter to this call.

so far I have

```
   const postRequest = {
      url: 'https://address',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'authorization': 'Basic xyz',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
     formData: {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
      }
    };
```

How do I include the id and secret into this request?
I have also tried

```
 formData: {
     'grant_type' : 'client_credentials',
     'client_id' :'id',
    'client_secret' : 'secret'
  }
```

that does not work either as stated in [How to use FormData for AJAX file upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use FormData for AJAX file upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: thanks for the link but it does not

Comment: Look at the header part: two key-value pairs. Your `formData` has one so far. Now just add the two additional ones, using the same format and commas in between. I don't see where the issue is.

Comment: this is the latest version that does not work 
 formData: {
     'grant_type' : 'client_credentials',
     'client_id' :'id',
    'client_secret' : 'secret'
  }

Comment: `'client_secret' : 'secret'` sends the actual six characters `"secret"`. If you have a variable `secret` you need to remove the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an OAuth2 flow, and it's most likely you need to pass this in your Basic authorization header.

```
  headers: {
    'authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(`${clientId}:${clientSecret}`),
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
```

It's even better to use a good existing OAuth2 library to handle the heavy lifting. I've open sourced mine:

https://github.com/badgateway/oauth2-client

it would work like this:

```js
const client = new OAuth2Client({
  tokenEndpoint: 'https://address',
  clientId: '...',
  clientSecret: '...',
});
const result = await client.clientCredentials();
```

Comment: I am using exactly what you are recommending, the one with just headers. Except I did not mention the actual value. I still need to send the form-data, correct?

Comment: @reza most OAuth2 servers require it in the Authorization header, some require it in the body but never both... so one of those should work. If it doesn't work, check out the error you are getting for a clue.

Comment: Will do, thank you. 
The error is 
status: "Method Not Allowed"
code: 405

Comment: @reza that suggests you have the wrong url.

Comment: absolutely. Thanks for sticking with this @evert

Comment: you are correct. Thank you for sticking with this @evert.

Comment: np. next time post the error first!